# Apple Developer Account has been deleted repeatedly

Tags: xcode, apple-id, apple-developer

Xcode & Apple developer account setting problem.

1. I opened exsiting xcode project on new mac.
2. Setup a apple developer account.
3. Build & deploy successfully.
4. Restart the Xcode.
5. Apple Developer Account has been deleted repeatedly.

I need your help...

Xcode Prefs. Account Setting:

[image]

Xcode Project Setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of Xcode. :(
Let's update!!!

Comment: (not clear if you are being serious or not). Can you provide more info (or open radar number)?